# How to use Webdrivers with selenium to automate edge

Tags: selenium, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am a total novice to powershell, and I want to make a powershell script that automatically adds sites onto edge to be launched in IE mode. I want this script to run in the background and not actually open an edge window. If anyone could provide me with a resource with the list of things I can actually do with selenium, and some pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate Edge IE mode using Selenium, I suggest that you can use other languages like C#, Python and Java. The detailed steps of using WebDriver with Selenium to automate Edge IE mode are in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=c-sharp). You can refer to it.

Comment: The reason I want to use PowerShell for this is that this needs to be deployed to a whole network of computers, and Powershell scripts are preferred for a lot of remote deployment here.